# Behavioral difference between `^x` and `^x.x.x`

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json, semantic-versioning

I want to allow yarn to update to all newer minor + patch versions, so I am using the caret.

If the latest version of "my-package" is "3.3.3", what are the behavioral differences between `"my-package": "^3"` and `"my-package": "^3.2.1"`?

If there is none, then is there a reasonable argument in favor of one or the other?

Comment: `^3` means any version equal or newer than 3, it could be 3.0.0, or 3.5.12 or anything in the 3.X.X range. `^3.2.1` is the same, but also at least 3.2.1, so it won't download 3.0.0 or 3.1.6, for example.

Comment: I'd suggest having a play with https://semver.npmjs.com/ so you can see what gets matched. Note that it will get more complicated with overlapping transitive dependencies - if something else requires e.g. `my-package@~3.1` then your two options would end up in different trees.